# How to use props and navigation route in same const function (react native)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native. I am trying to use props and navigation in a const function. I do not know how to do that.

```
    render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.state.signedIn ? (
      <LoggedInPage name={this.state.name} photoUrl={this.state.photoUrl} />
    ) : (
      <LoginPage signIn={this.signIn} />
    )}
    <TouchableOpacity 
     onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('About You')}}
      style={styles.submitButton4}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText2}> Next </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
   );
```

}
const LoggedInPage = props => {
return (

Welcome {props.name}
<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: props.photoUrl }} />

 Change photo 

<TouchableOpacity
onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('registration')}}
style={styles.submitButton4}>
 Next 


)
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your LoggedInPage is one of the screens defined in the Navigator, then the navigation prop is automatically passed into your component. you can then use navigation like so `props.navigation.navigate`

all you need is pass in the navigation prop from your parent.

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.state.signedIn ? (
      <LoggedInPage name={this.state.name} photoUrl={this.state.photoUrl} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    ) : (
      <LoginPage signIn={this.signIn} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    )}
    <TouchableOpacity 
     onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('About You')}}
      style={styles.submitButton4}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText2}> Next </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
   );
```

then you can use it the name way:

```
const LoggedInPage = props => {

return (

  <Text style={styles.text1}>Welcome {props.name}</Text>
  <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: props.photoUrl }} />

  <TouchableOpacity 
       
       style={styles.submitButton1}> 
       <Text style={styles.buttonText3}> Change photo </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity 
     onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('registration')}}
      style={styles.submitButton4}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText2}> Next </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
) }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it did not work. My Login and Logged In page are in same screen called Homescreen. I got an error "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate'). The user signs in using google account and after clicking his google account, he goes to logged In page (shown above).

Comment: can you post your navigator code? or where do call the LoggedInPage? That means it's not part of the navigator.

Comment: Hii Wen.. Here it is:render() {
    return (
      
      <View style={styles.container}>
          {this.state.signedIn ? (
          <LoggedInPage name={this.state.name} photoUrl={this.state.photoUrl} />
        ) : (
          <LoginPage signIn={this.signIn} />
        )}
        <TouchableOpacity 
         onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('About You')}}
          style={styles.submitButton4}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText2}> Next </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
       );
} 
}

Comment: i know what the problem is, update your question with this code and I can provide an answer.

Comment: I am soory. I am new in stack overflow also. I have changed it

Comment: Thank you so much Wen W. It worked. Please Connect me in Linkedln: www.linkedin.com/in/ankit-verma007

Comment: please mark this as the answer if it worked for you. :)

Comment: marked it. it says thanks for the feedback and the votes are recorded

Comment: I think you marked something else. It should have a green checkmark if you marked it as an answer.

Comment: I marked it and it shows this: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.